# Magento 2 Default JS doesn't load proper

Tags: magento2, javascript, bug

Magento 2 is broken in admin panel and add to cart does not work.

I have checked both **pub/static/frontend/Magento/Theme/en_US/mage/dropdown.js**

and

**pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/i18n.js** doesn't load proper.

Comment: Have you try with this below command? which error are generate in log file

Answer (score 0):

you have to run deploy command,

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Remove **var** folder and remove cache.

Clear Browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

Follow Below Commend

1)php bin/magento cache:clean
2)bin/magento cache:flush
3)php bin/magento setup:upgrade
4)php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy